# Aligning arrow on the right

Tags: css, alignment

I am trying to build a carousel with left and right arrows. How do I align the right arrow to the very right side of the screen? I looked through many post to figure it out, tried both float and align, can't figure it out.

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agassi0430/CcAMD/

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easiest to use `position: absolute;` on the arrows and align them using `right: 0;` `left: 0;` . You also have to remember to set `position: relative;` to the element that contains them in order for the position absolute to work within that container.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CcAMD/11/).

Also, watch out for your html markup. It's not valid to put anything other than `<li><li>` (list item) in between `<ul></ul>` (unordered list)

Comment: Thanks Rick. Didn't realize you couldn't set divs inside ul

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    <div class="category">Most Discussed</div>
    <div class="contents">    
        <ul><div class="leftarrow"></div></ul>
        <ul><div class="content"></div>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li></ul>
        <ul style="float:right;"><div class="rightarrow"></div></ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help if you can remove the arrows from the list...but if you need to keep them in the list, try messing around with the display properties. Such as display: inline-block; in your css. Be careful though, some of those don't degrade very nicely in older versions of IE. You may need a minor css hack for IE 7...